# Viewing startup logs of docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile

How can we view container startup logs of docker. (ie: when container is starting up viz boot.log in Jboss for eg. as in what all events are kicking up while container is coming up.)

As of now I can view any event in logs when container comes up, but I cannot find any mechanism to view logs when container is starting up.

Any idea?

Comment: "As of now I can view any event in logs when container comes up, but I cannot find any mechanism to view logs when container is starting up." can you phrase that differently? It appears to be self contradictory.

Comment: It depends on the container (image). The rule is for containers to redirect any logs to stderr/stdout so that they can be aggregated by the docker daemon using whatever logging plugin you chose.
Post the steps to create your container and we'll be able help you further. As a rule, put code code code... in this case, your command lines used, Dockerfile, `docker version` and `docker info`.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking? This doesn't really make sense, anything that writes to stdout/err have logs that are visible to Docker (even if the container fails to start, you can still receive them).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion: I mean to say suppose I started a container and I wan to see the logs of event s happening during container startup (including steps which docker engine is doing in order to run the container). Is there any way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got a way to do that.

1) First do "docker events&" where you want to run you container.

2) Then run your container like:

docker run -d .... (Full command)
It will generate a Hex Id for container (look out at the end).

(container=f1b76ae5a75a1443c01181de46767gbb03621167d019f5d26d3e5131d9158843511a69, name=bridge, type=bridge)

3) Now go in another window and see the logs: 
docker logs  (from previous step)

This is especially useful if your container is not coming up properly.